# Is this a good enough proof by induction?

Tags: proof-writing, induction, solution-verification

I am trying to understand induction. Is the proof good enough to satisfy what was looked for? If not, do you have any feedback for me?

> To show: $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 ≤ n^3$ for any $n = 0, 1, 2,\ldots$

If $P(n)$ holds then $P(n+1)$ holds as well $\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} i^2 ≤ (n+1)^3$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} i^2 = \sum_{i=0}^n i^2 + (n+1)^2 ≤ n^3 + (n+1)^2 ≤ (n+1)^3$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 + (n+1)^2 ≤ n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1$$

By the inductive hypothesis $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 ≤ n^3$

$(n+1)^2 ≤ 3n^2 + 3n + 1$

$3n+1 ≤ 3n^2$ and
$(n+1)^2 ≤ 3n^2$

Thus, holds for $n+1$ and proof of induction is complete.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thank you and fixed.

Comment: Looks ok. But like many induction proofs in exercises, this one seems artificial. A simple proof is $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^n n^2 = n^3$.

Comment: It is equivalent to $$n (n+1) (2n+1)\le 6n^3$$ or $$4n^3\geq3n^2+n$$ which is true when $n\geq1$

Comment: In general, don't forget to show the base case ;)

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone If I remember correctly, OP had written it in the photo he had posted in the first version of the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the proof seems right, it is not written correctly. Mainly it **seems** like you assume the claim throughout (even though you don't). Following would be a better way to write it:

Assume $P(n)$ is true, that is $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 \leq n^3.$ We want to show $\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} i^2 \leq (n+1)^3.$

Consider
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} i^2 &= \sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2 + (n+1)^2\\
&\leq n^3 + (n+1)^2\hspace{1cm} \text{(by induction hypothesis)}\\
&= n^3 + n^2+2n+1\\
&\leq n^3 +3n^2+3n+1\\
&=(n+1)^3. 
\end{align*}

Hence $P(n+1)$ holds.

Answer (score 5):

[Sahiba Arora’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3628286/2439) shows how to write the induction step more clearly.  But besides that **you also need to show the base case $P(0)$**.  So I would write the whole proof something like:

**Proof.**  We work by induction on $n$.

The base case $P(0)$ states that $\sum_{i=0}^0 i^2 \leq 0^2$, i.e. $0 \leq 0$, which certainly holds.

For the induction step, assume $P(n)$ is true… [continued as in [Sahiba Arora’s excellent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3628286/2439)].

So by induction, the given inequality holds for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: Great addition! The only reason I didn't add the base case was that OP had written it in the first version of the question.